# getExpireTime() getDriver() in Laravel 4 SessionServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 4 has a class SessionServiceProvider. How can I use some of the methods in it such as getExpireTime(), getDriver() within my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get lifetime you can use MetadataBag: `Session::getFacadeRoot()->getMetadataBag()->getLifeTime()`